# Connect Android Virtual Device to Live Server

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code, mobile-website, npm-live-server

I'm a novice programmer trying to write a front-end web app in vanilla JS that resizes and looks great & functions correctly on iOS and Android. Specifically, I'm troubleshooting how browsers change focus location when their onscreen keyboards open.

Currently, I can open a simulated iPhone in Xcode and navigate to the live server IP/port however I cannot do the same with the Android virtual device using Android Studio. When entering the IP/port in the search bar I get an error that says the connection was refused.

My goal is to be able to have an iPhone and Android virtual devices responding to the changes I make in the code each time I save so that I can determine the best way to fix the bugs I've come across in the wild that don't show up in Chrome dev tools on my laptop.

I've spent some time Googling the issue but I think I lack the vocabulary required to find a solution. Could you help me understand what I need to search for to find the solution or a helpful link to the documentation for Android Studio?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution.

The IP address of my liver server was 127.0.0.162:portnumber/index.html which can be accessed by the virtual device created in Xcode but not by Android Studio.

The solution was to navagate to my machines IP Address 10.0.0.XXX:portnumber/index.html

[You can find a more detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436618/why-cant-i-enter-the-url-on-my-phones-browser-to-view-my-live-site)